# how to perform Step calcuations in R

Tags: r

I have a rate-step plan for consumption with which I'm trying to total up costs. I have a rate plant that looks like this:

```
First 20 Kwh is Free; 
Second 5 Kwh is $.1
    Next 100 Kwh is $.053 
Next 875 Kwh is $.042 
    Over 1000Kwh is $.039
```

Can someone provide a worked example for me, e.g., with $\text{consumtpion}=625$? If possible, with R code for calculating the total cost.

For my own approach, I was thinking of using a loop, but if it's a lot of accounts the loop will take too long.  Can anyone think of a vector-based approach for calculating the result?

Comment: Yes a worked example would be useful, from you, to tell us how much a consumption of 625 would cost. You could do this very easily.

Comment: Did any of the existing answers solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a simple equation like this:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\max(x-20,0)*0.1 + \max(0,x-25)*(-.047) + \\
&&\max(0, x-125)*(-.011) + \max(0,x-1000)*(-.003)
\end{eqnarray}

This should take the usage $(x)$ and walk it through steps, initially charging 0.1 for each Kwh over 20: $\max(x-20,0)*0.1$

Then, if $x$ is above 20, it takes away 0.047 (0.1-0.053) for every Kwh between 20 and 25: $\max(0, x-25)*(-0.047)$

Then, if $x$ is above 125, it takes away 0.011 (0.053-0.042) for every Kwh between 25 and 125: $\max(0, x-125)*(-0.011)$

Comment: I'm sorry Duncan, I thought I tagged it already.  Thanks much. This did work for me.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naïve implementation of your pseudocode in R:

```
calculate_cost <- function(kwh){
    if(kwh < 20){
        return(0)
    }else{
         kwh <- kwh - 20
    if(kwh <= 5){
        return(kwh * 0.1)
    }else{
        final_cost <- kwh * 0.1
        kwh <- kwh - 5
        if(kwh <= 100){
            return(final_cost + (kwh * 0.053))
        }else{
            final_cost <- final_cost + (kwh * 0.053)
            kwh <- kwh - 100
            if(kwh <= 875){
                return(final_cost + (kwh * 0.042))
            }else{
                final_cost <- final_cost + (kwh * 0.042)
                kwh <- kwh - 875
                return(final_cost + (kwh * 0.039))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then,

```
> calculate_cost(kwh=625)
[1] 113.3
```